# Correctness of Measurement

Tags: coordinate-system, gps

I tried Google, but the questions isn't that easy to put in Google, so I haven't found anything about this.
I am making a database with different locations (latitude and longitude).
For this I have two GPS systems, a differential and a non-differential. My question is, can the positions measured by the different systems be compared?
As I understand, the accuracy is only a statistical value.  So if the accuracy tells you 5 cm, you know that the systems are measuring in this radius. But how do you know that the measurements are correct to begin with?

When I complete the database, I can compare further measurements made with it to check the performance of the GPS.  Is it then better to make the database with the differential, or make two different ones because I can't compare the two systems with each other?

Comment: You've got several questions in your Question, which makes it quite difficult to answer.  Please **edit** this Question to focus on your most pressing issue.

Comment: @Vince Because the questions are so closely related, and an answer to the first is likely to suggest answers to the second, I would like to suggest keeping them together rather than creating multiple threads.  Sanny: do you have accuracy estimates for *both* GPS systems?  Are the measurements in the two systems made independently?  (This would mean, in particular, that they were performed at different sets of times.)

Comment: Yes I have estimates for both systems. For the differential it's 2 cm and for then non it's 3 m.  Most of my measurements were made at the same time, with the two different systems.